# How to get esbuild to include internal dependencies when using typescript

Tags: typescript, esbuild

I am working on a vscode extension and am using `esbuild` to do the bundling/minification. I want to use the [jsonc-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonc-parser) NPM module. When I do this, `esbuild` runs OK but the extension won't load, giving an error "Activating extension failed: Cannot find module './impl/format'".
I can reproduce this in a smaller example than the whole vscode extension, see the following:

Main file

```
import * as jsonc from 'jsonc-parser'
const example = '// Some comment\n{"a":1,"b":2}'
console.log(`Parsing ${example}`)
const errors = []
const mexample = jsonc.parse(example, errors)
console.log(`Result: ${JSON.stringify(mexample, null, 2)}`)
console.log(`Errors: ${JSON.stringify(errors)}`)
```

Relevant bits of `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "run-bundle": "node out.js",
    "bundle": "esbuild index.ts --bundle --platform=node --outfile=out.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jsonc-parser": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "esbuild": "^0.12.28"
  }
```

In the bundled out.js I can see

```
      var formatter = require2("./impl/format");
      var edit = require2("./impl/edit");
      var scanner = require2("./impl/scanner");
      var parser = require2("./impl/parser");
```

So it looks like `esbuild` hasn't picked these 'internal dependencies' up for bundling.

I've tried some options in `tsconfig.json` and `package.json` with no success.

Answer (score 3):

I raised an [issue](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1619) on GitHub and received the following explanation and work-around from user hyrious

> This is because the jsonc-parser library exports a UMD file which uses require() indirectly, which prevents esbuild to analyze and bundle these dependencies. As a quick solution, you could use its ESM target in the module field by appending this option: --main-fields=module,main.

and from evanw

> Having esbuild handle this automatically is out of scope since esbuild only handles require calls that can be statically-evaluated at compile time without partially-evaluating the input JavaScript code. The package not being bundler-friendly is a problem with the package, not with esbuild.
> As mentioned above, workarounds are:
>
> - Use --main-fields=module,main (may cause issues with other packages)
> - Write an esbuild plugin using onResolve to swap out just this one file (won't affect other packages)
> - Get Microsoft to make their code bundler-friendly

Comment: I did file an issue with jsonc-parser too, it's https://github.com/microsoft/node-jsonc-parser/issues/57